# adding labels to ggplot2 point based on column variables

Tags: r, ggplot2, label, scatter-plot, scatter

I am trying to add labels to my scatter plot based on another columns variables.

`ggplot(differentrace, aes(x=DifferentRace, y=Parents)) + geom_point() + geom_text(label=rownames(differentrace))`

My table is

```
      Parents             Different Race 
1    1 UK born           2.32
2    Both UK born        2.58
3    Neither             2.24
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gQrxG.png)

This is my output, instead of the 1,2,3 labels I would like the labels to be 1 UK born, Both UK born, or Neither. Also I would like to offset the labels slightly to not obstruct the data points.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried `geom_text(aes(label=Parents), vjust = -0.5)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

R doesn't consider your `Parents` column as row names. Instead, it's just another column! So here's the code: `ggplot(differentrace, aes(x=DifferentRace, y=Parents)) + geom_point() + ggrepel::geom_text_repel(aes(label = Parents))`. I used `ggrepel::geom_text_repel` to move the text labels away from the points.

Additionally, you have to wrap `label = Parents` in an `aes()` call because you want each point to be labelled with the corresponding `Parent` from the same dataframe; if you don't use `aes()`, R doesn't know what `Parent` refers to.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't 100% sure what you want to do. So, I exchanged x and y-axis, made the x-axis as a factor and used `nudge_y`to adjust the text. As text the values in the variable `Parents` are used.

```r
library(ggplot2)

differentrace <- read.table(text = 
"
Parents             DifferentRace 
'1 UK born'           2.32
'Both UK born'        2.58
'Neither'             2.24 
", header=T)


ggplot(differentrace, aes(x=factor(Parents), y=DifferentRace, 
                      label = Parents)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  geom_text(nudge_y = .05) +
  labs(x = '', y ='Different Race')
```

[image]

Comment: cheers thanks, just cracked it at the sane time you answered ahah, thanks for the help